# Couldn't get desired output... AlarmManager and PendingIntent

Tags: android

I am creating a program for call reminder where user enters the Name and phone number of person to whom he/she wants to make call and date and time when he/she wants to get reminder.While running the application, when I don't change 
DatePicker view, event takes place at right time. But when I change DatePicker view, 
event takes place immediately on clicking on submit button.
I think the problem here is that new object of Calendar is created in both onDateSet() and onTimeSet() method and variable timePicked doesn't get the value of both onDateSet() and onTimeSet() method!Can you plzz help me in onDateSet() method?
This is very important for me for interview purpose.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static EditText text;
    public static EditText text2;
    //public static int hour,minute,month,day,year;
public static long timePicked = -1;

static Calendar c;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        c= new GregorianCalendar();

        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
                if (timePicked != -1) {
                    MyBroadcastReceiver alarm = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
                    if(alarm != null) alarm.setOnetimeTimer(MainActivity.this,timePicked);

                    btn.setText("ALARM SET");
                    Log.d("test", "ALARM SET!!!");
                } else {
                    //warn the user for ALARM not set?
                    Log.w("test", "ALARM not SET!!!");
                }
            }
        });

    }






public static class TimePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current time as the default values for the picker
//final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// Create a new instance of TimePickerDialog and return it
return new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, hour, minute,DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getActivity()));
}
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
         //Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
            c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

           // timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
            Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
            Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
    }

}

public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new TimePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"timePicker");
}
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// Use the current date as the default date in the picker
//final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
//long millis=c.getTimeInMillis(); 
// Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
}

public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
// Do something with the date chosen by the user
    //Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, month);
    //datePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
    Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
    Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
}
}
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(),"datePicker");
}




}
```

MyBroadCastReceiver.java

```
  public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "test");

        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Call"+MainActivity.text.getText()+MainActivity.text2.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("test", "ALARM!!!");
        showNotification(context);
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

        //Release the lock

        wl.release();
    }
    private void showNotification(Context context) {
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle("My notification")
                .setContentText("Call"+MainActivity.text.getText()+MainActivity.text2.getText());
        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
        mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context, long when) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
    }
}
```

XML

```
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="NAME" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:text="Phone" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Set Reminder Time" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:onClick="showTimePickerDialog"
        android:text="Select Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
        android:text="Set Reminder Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:onClick="showDatePickerDialog"
        android:text="Select Date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: is there any problem in declaring three classes as public out of which two are fragment?

Comment: alarmManager.set() method ..wht will be the correct code for that so that i can set the reminder at the specified time and date set by the user

Comment: When I click on "Set Time" and "Set Date" button it shows "unfortunately activity has stopped"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

and

```
<receiver android:name="YOUR.PACKAGE.NAME.MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```

Last line requires external class file for the receiver:
so, `MyBrodcastReceiver.java` now is:

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "test");

        //Acquire the lock
        wl.acquire();

        Toast.makeText(context, "Call", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i("test", "ALARM!!!");

        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(2000);

        //Release the lock
        wl.release();
    }

    public void setOnetimeTimer(Context context, long when) {
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
        am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, when, pi);
    }
}
```

Then call `setOnetimeTimer` to set the alarm in `MainActivity`'s `onCreate`:

```
public static long timePicked = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final Button btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (timePicked != -1) {
                MyBroadcastReceiver alarm = new MyBroadcastReceiver();
                if(alarm != null) alarm.setOnetimeTimer(MainActivity.this, timePicked);

                btn.setText("ALARM SET");
                Log.d("test", "ALARM SET!!!");
            } else {
                //warn the user for ALARM not set?
                Log.w("test", "ALARM not SET!!!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Last and **IMPORTANT**, get the time from the `TimePickerFragment` changing `onTimeSet` to this:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);

    timePicked = c.getTimeInMillis();
    Log.d("test", "timePicked: " + timePicked);
    Log.d("test", "current: " + System.currentTimeMillis() );
}
```

Tested and Working.
Happy coding.

PS: Please note that at this point the date picker is not taken into account.

Comment: It seems. Did you try with the Manifest?

Comment: yeah..When I click on "Set Time" and "Set Date" button it shows "unfortunately activity has stopped" and

Comment: alarmManager.set() method ..wht will be the correct code for that so that i can set the reminder at the specified time and date set by the user

Comment: is there any problem in declaring three classes as public out of which two are fragment?

Comment: And anyway, are you trying to use the time picker for the alarm? because you seems to not use `onTimeSet`.

Comment: logcat posted..yeah i am trying to use time picker and date picker for alarm so that reminder will be displayed at choosen date nd time by user

Comment: alarmManager.set() method ..wht will be the correct code for that so that i can set the reminder at the specified time and date set by the user

Comment: solved the error about clicking button..but still there is problem in AlarmManager and PendingIntent

Comment: Yes you are assigning the `onClick` to the wrong button (the one for the time picker). You need an extra button.

Comment: yeah..i solved that..but still when i click on Select Date and Submit button error comes "unfortunately application has stopped"..i am posting my modified program within 2 minutes.thanks for the help

Comment: see my updated MainActiivity and xml layout..I'll update MyBroadcastReceiver as u said..SelectTime Button working fine but SelectDate and Submit button not working..thanks for ur time

Comment: Updated answer with full solution (I said "you seems to not use `onTimeSet` ...)  ;)

Comment: Thanks..i'll update my code and test it too within 15 minutes

Comment: @user3503165 Glad it helped. I learned something too, testing the code.

Comment: Sir,I have updated my question according to your answer.Also I have added notification to BroadCast Receiver so that notification is
created along with toast at the time of reminder.I have updated onDateSet() method but it is creating problem.While running the application, when I don't change DatePicker view, event takes place at right time. But when I change DatePicker view, event takes place immediately on clicking on submit button.I think the problem here is that new object of Calendar is created in both onDateSet() and onTimeSet() method

Comment: and variable timePicked doesn't get the value of both onDateSet() and onTimeSet() method!Can you plzz help me in onDateSet() method?
This is very important for me for interview purpose.You can see my updated program in question.

Comment: Please, do it yourself, with this instructions... It's important that you understand how you reach your goals. - Yes, the problem is that the new `GregorianCalendar` is recreated when you set every picker. So: make `Calendar c` a singleton. `onCreate` should be a good place to initialize it (that is: `c = new GregorianCalendar()`). Then leave the logic where you set its month, day, hour etc in place where it is now). Then move the 2 `timePicked` assignments to have only one, when you click the button3. It should work.

Comment: Sir,I updated my question as per your instructions.Now the problem is that the reminder notification is displayed as soon as user hits Submit button.Thats may be bcoz the notification is displayed at System's time(emulator or phone time) rather than the time and date selected by user.Could you give me hint of where the problem is actually?..u can see my code in the question

Comment: working on it for hours..even when I write .set() methods inside onClick() it doesn't work

Comment: Hey dentex! I have posted my problem as question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474947/reminder-notification-issue ..I'll select your answer as best answer if you answer that as I know it'll be correct..its very important for me for interview purpose.I am srill learning android